# Devolver lista con los valores de un dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

Me gustaría crear una lista de canciones con un dataframe que tengo y lo que quiero es que me devuelva los valores que sigan ciertas características pero usando el porcentaje en el que salen en la numpy
array.

````
array([ 0, -2,  0, -2, -2, -1,  0,  0,  0, -1, -2, -1,  0,  0, -2,  0, -1,
       -1, -1, -2, -1, -1, -2, -1,  0,  0, -2,  0,  0, -2, -2,  0, -2, -1,
        0, -2, -2, -2, -1,  0,  0, -2, -1,  0, -1, -2, -1, -2, -1, -1, -2,
       -2, -1,  0,  0,  0, -2,  0,  0,  0,  0, -1,  0, -1, -2, -2,  0, -2,
       -1,  0, -1,  0,  0,  0, -2, -2, -2,  0,  0, -1, -1, -1, -2,  0,  0,
       -1, -2,  0, -1, -1,  0, -2, -1, -1, -2,  0, -2, -2,  0,  0]) ```

Este es el código que estoy utilizando
````

```
def reco(b):

    counter = collections.Counter(b)
    size=b.size
    for k,v in counter.items():
        k,{int(v/size*100)}

    n= {int(v/size*100)}
    hey=[]
    hey.append(spotify[spotify['intervals']==-2](['track_name'].sample(n=(), random_state=1)))
    hey.append(spotify[spotify['intervals']==-1](['track_name'].sample(n=(), random_state=1)))
    hey.append(spotify[spotify['intervals']==-0](['track_name'].sample(n=(), random_state=1)))
    return hey
```

Lo estoy usando para crear un sistema de recomendación de canciones el numpy array es el resultado de una clasificación de ml.

Quiero que me devuelva una lista con las canciones cuyo valor en la columna intervals es -1,pero sobre el porcentaje de la numpy array.Por ejemplo: en la numpy array tengo un porcentje de un 30% para -1(hay un 0.3 sobre el total de -1)devuelve una lista con las canciones que sean -1 en un 30%

```
'Music of My Heart',
 'Eight Days A Week - Remastered 2009',
 'Number One',
 "It's My Life",
 'I Believe in a Thing Called Love',
 'Making Plans For Nigel',
 'Trouble',
 "Operator (That's Not The Way It Feels)",
 'Montreal',
 'Walk Idiot Walk',
 'Patek',
 'No Money - Dillon Francis Remix',
 'I Wanna Love You',
 'Wheelz of Steel',
 'Never Gonna Give You Up',
 'Let My Baby Stay',
 "Can't You See - Original Mix",
 'Team',
 'Emily',
 'Paris 12',
 'Carry You Home',
 'How I Could Just Kill a Man',
 'Alive',
 'MOB',
 'HandClap',
```

Comment: Podrías completar tu pregunta con el output y/o errores?

Comment: No queda muy claro lo que quieres hacer. ¿Podrías adjuntar un ejemplo de los que esperas?

Answer (score 0):

Creo que veo varios fallos que deberías de revisar:

1. Haces loop a una variable `spotify` que asumo que es un diccionario pero solo iteras sobre su clave en `i`, que además tampoco usas luego en el loop.
2. Condicionas sobre la key "intervals" y usas el método .item que me parece que no es válido, y los tres condicionales son sobre la misma key y aunque cambia el valor "==" el resultado del condicional es el mismo `.append` para los tres.
3. Haces referencia en los condicionales a la variable `v` que creo que haces referencia en el loop de antes de la variable `counter`, pero esa variable solo tiene un scope localizado a ese bucle, cuando termina esa variable no se sigue usando y se destruye, por lo que tampoco puedes usarla en el condicional porque `ya no existe`

Échale un vistazo a esos detalles y ya vemos después

Comment: Spotify en un dataframe aunque claro raw es un diccionario

Comment: He conseguido generar una lista aleatoria usando esto``` b=a['intervals'].sample(n=5, random_state=1)
b.to_list
b``` mi out es ```track_name
Music of My Heart                      0
Eight Days A Week - Remastered 2009    0
Number One                            -1
It's My Life                          -2
I Believe in a Thing Called Love      -1``` Ahora cómo lo hago con los porcentajes??